# Passing data from component to another page so it can reference the ID and do something

Tags: json, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I have code below so you can all take a look. Right now when a user clicks on an image I have it in my component below it will say in the browser /watch/9 which is great but when I go to another page how can I reference that data the ID of 9 which the user chose to then play the video within that same JSON object? Thanks for any help I would greatly appreciate.

```
0:
id: 9
title: "Stuff"
description: "1. Some stuff"
video_path: "stuff.com/videos/1/9/9.mp4"
video_date: "some date"
poster_path: "stuff.com/Videos/1/9/9poster.jpg"
poster_date: "None"
user_id: 2
category: 1
deleted: 0
username: "SomeUser"
```

I have this component that just builds cards with poster of the video and other data.

```
import React from "react"
import "../styles/VideoCards.css"

export default function VideoData({ img, title, username, id }) {
    return (
        <div className="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 p-3">
            <div className="card">
                <a className="img-hover" href={`/watch/${id}`}><img src={img} className="card-img-top rounded" alt="" /></a>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <a href="" className="link-hover"><h5 className="card-title">{title}</h5></a>
                    <a href="" className="link-hover"><p className="card-text font-weight-bold">{username}</p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This container which just gets the data and is able to output the data.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react"
import {postVideos} from "../services/MyCuruApi"
import VideoData from "../components/VideoData"

export default function VideoContainer() {
    const [videoIds, setVideoIds] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        postVideos().then(data => setVideoIds(data))
    }, [])
    console.log(videoIds)

    return videoIds.map(videoId => 
    <VideoData 
    img={videoId.poster_path}
    title={videoId.title}
    username={videoId.username}
    id={videoId.id}
    video={videoId.video_path}
    /> )
}
```

Comment: can pass id in query parameter of URL,  `href={`/watch/${id}?id=${id}`} ` and access the URL `window.location.href`, you can use URL object to parse the url

Comment: @Jem you want particular selected vedio in url and data in navigated component?

Comment: @harsh I shall give that a shot. @ Vahid Yes, so I have different videos think of youtube lots of different videos and a user clicks one and that data passed onto another page with that particular video they chose. The JSON object of ID is 9 which is referencing the video since it is apart of the same JSON. So the goal is they click any of the videos, the ID is already within the JSON then it goes to another page with the ID so something.com/watch/9 and the video plays.

Comment: When you are in new page from the url something.com/watch/9 you can get the Id=9 and according the Id you can get the object form your data source. Then set the state. It's the easiest way for the new page.

Comment: @ Palash So when I go to the new page I will need to setup a new component to render that particular page but how do I get the ID and set the state of which is being passed from the previous page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll get the ID by introducing params in the route.

For instance, in route, I'll write something like this:

```
<Route exact path='/watch/:id/' render={(props) => (
    <VideoContainer{...props} />
 )} />
```

Then in the *VideoContainer*, I'll call the ID from the URL with this piece of code:

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot.

Comment: So I am still working on it. But it's very late now so I am going to have to check back.